# How do I get to Fens Camp?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I can't figure out how to get to Fens Camp in the Exalted Plains. I've been trying for hours to get to it but I cannot find a way. I repaired the northern bridge and did the ramparts quest but I still am unable to get to it. How do you? I'm trying to finish the inner circle quest *Unfinished Business* and this is the last person I have to take out.

Answer (score 3):

The entrance to that region is a little hidden. It is almost directly south of Pont Agur (that northern bridge you repaired) and east of the Riverwatch Camp:

[image: Map of the Exalted Plains]

Once you're there, there will be one of the dog-ish statues. Behind it is a collapsed passage. You will need to activate a War Table operation to clear the rubble.

[image]

Once that is cleared, you'll have to fight a few Gurguts before you can set up camp.

Answer (score 1):

There is a collapsed cave a bit south of the camp with an operation in it that will clear all the rubble. Once executed it will open up that cave, clearing the path to the campsite. After that it's a matter of following the path.